No explanation provided for "TRANSACTION FEE" on Chase Sapphire Preferred card transaction
On the list of transactions for our Chase Sapphire Preferred card on chase.com, I see $19.06 "TRANSACTION FEE" transaction. No other description available.
It's been just about a month since we started using this card.
Tried googling but found no relevant information so far. Multiple sources suggest foreign transaction fee but we doubt we've made any foreign purchase using this card recently.

UPDATE: My intent of asking this question was more for general purpose. Printing "transaction fee" on bank account transaction withOUT clarifying who withdraws the money is not super helpful so I kind of wanted to see if there's general rule of thumb when you see "transaction fee" on the transaction. I wasn't asking about my particular case, for which I agree I should consult my own financial institution.

Have you tried asking Chase?

What transactions have you done while using your card? Purchases made abroad, even if made sitting in your home via the magic of the internet and online ordering, may incur a Transaction Fee in an amount that can be surprisingly large compared to the picayune purchase price

You “doubt”?? Why don’t you actually look through the transaction history and confirm?

The CSP doesn't have foreign transaction fees. Could it be a bounced payment or an overdraft? You'll need to call Chase.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service question and not about PF&M

The general rule of thumb is, in fact, to contact the financial institution.

As for whether there are types of transactions that tend to be categorized and have description of "transaction fee" in general, I don't know yet.
As for the specific case of my own asked in the OP, it was the paymend done on Venmo that I used Chase Sapphire card (Chase' customer support told us). You should talk to your financial institution when you need a clarification about a transaction as multiple people in this thread suggest though.
